# Problem with lp command on raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, printing

I have a problem with my hp laserjet p1005 printer on Raspberry pi 3. Actually, for some pdf documents, the `lp` command doesn't print the document correctly . The printed page is weird (the first picture bellow) and when I use `xpdf` the page is perfect.

Is there anybody that may help me solving this problem?

[image: Printed document using <code>lp</code> command]
[image: The same document printed using <code>xpdd</code>]